# Maria-Db reading index after load into memory

Tags: join, select, optimization, mariadb

I'm working with 2 tables in separate databases. t01 has approx 10,000,000 records, c01 has 150,000 records. please note this is very stripped down from the overall project just to get to the problem area.

```
LOAD INDEX INTO CACHE temp1.t01;
select * from temp1.t01 inner join temp2.c01 on temp1.t01.x3 = temp2.c01.x3 limit 1;
```

If there is a match there will only be one. I mainly need to know if it exists. Even though I don't currently see why it behaves this way I am open to suggestions to optimize this query.

The problem I'm having is even after using the load into cache command I watch the resource monitor and it is showing temp1/t01.msi being read. this comparison takes approx 15 seconds. As I stated this is stripped down for testing. There are thousands of these comparisons against temp1.t01.

```
key buffer 8,​589,​934,​592
mrr buffer      262,​144
myisam sort buffer      8,​589,​934,​592
net buffer      8,​192
preload buffer  1,073,741,824
```

running on windows 10 with 24GB RAM
Server version: 10.4.11-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

```
USE temp1;
CREATE TABLE `t01` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `x3` binary(32) NOT NULL,
  `loopcount` bigint(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `t01`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `x3` (`x3`);
ALTER TABLE `t01`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

USE temp2; Substitute c01 for second table.

Comment: What is c54?  t01 is not in the query, so why discuss it?

Comment: Sorry c54 should have been t01. Corrected it in question.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT...`.

Answer (score 0):

The index on x3 needs to be on the larger table.  That way, the Optimizer will scan the smaller table until it finds a match.

Comment: The index on x3 is on all tables